# Azure function sends chunked response and Dialogflow does not process it

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, dialogflow-es

I am creating a  Google action using Dialog flow with a webhook implemented as an Azure function written in c#. I have run into a problem that using .net core 2 that the response sent back from the Azure function is being chunked but that Dialog flow does not understand the chunked response. Though it was possible to switch off chunking with the full .net framework it seems harder to do with .net core 2. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Thanks

I searched online and is that I am not the only person running into this problem but I have not yet seen a solution that works with .net core

My expectation is that when Dialog flow calls the webhook that it receives a response it can process.

Comment: What error message or other indication that it is not processing the chunked reply correctly?

Comment: Hi @Martin, if you have verified the latest bits work for you, could you accept my answer to close the question?

Answer (score 0):

The chunked response problem has been [fixed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/3851)(Enabling buffering for all requests) since [runtime 2.0.12265](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265) was released, right now see `2.0.12285.0`(In portal, Function app settings, Runtime version) on my side.